# Use a map service exposed via ArcGIS REST API as a data source in Data Integration Extension ETL tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-rest-api, spatial-etl

I am trying to use the SpatialETL tool in ESRIs Data Integration Extension to cut out rasters from a map service exposed via a REST URL on the following format

`http://utility.arcgis.com/usrsvcs/servers/REDACTED/rest/services/REDACTED/MapServer`

How can I use this data as a data source in the SpatialETL tool?

It works fine as a layer in ArcGIS Pro but I am failing to get it to load from the ETL tool.

Comment: What is your ETL Tool? (that might help you get the the right answer).

Comment: @Mapperz ESRI Data Integration Extension

Comment: So FME in (ESRI clothing).

Comment: @Mapperz, yes, I think that is the case (I am trying to learn this tool to evaluate if it fits our purposes so I am a beginner at this)

Comment: FME can read Esri ArcGIS Online (AGOL) Feature Service (not the Mapserver) QGIS can do both.

Comment: @Mapperz, so you are saying that as long as we try to use FME as our ETL tool we can not access that data source (without dumping it somewhere else first)

Comment: Do you have a real url we can test? (have ArcGIS Pro and FME and QGIS to test)

Comment: @Mapperz, sorry I do not think I am supposed to share the real URL